# bitcoin core problem payment

Tags: transactions, synchronization, payment, money-transfer, wire-transfers

I downloading bitcoin core on my computer. But my computer is full, and downloading is not complete. I made transfer my bitcoin to URI on bitcoin core, which downloading. But nothing came and I didn't seen. Becouse you wrote information "bitcoin can be see only when downloading when will be done" And my question is, where is my bitcoin money, when downloading is failed . regards

Answer (score 2):

> where is my bitcoin money, when downloading is failed.

Your money is in the Blockchain (loosely speaking). It is not affected by the state of your wallet. When your wallet finishes collecting its own copy of the public Blockchain (synchronisation), it will be able to show you the amount of money you control.

---

Some explanation:

A wallet does two things. Firstly it creates a local copy of the Blockchain and keeps it up to date. Secondly it stores a secret number that gives control over some money in the Blockchain.

Everyone with a traditional  "full-node" wallet has their own copy of the Blockchain. This is just a list of all the transactions. A transaction records changes in control over amounts of money.

Bitcoins are not really sent to wallets and are not stored in wallets. As long as you have a safe copy of the secret number (private key) or a wallet recovery phrase, it doesn't matter what happens to the wallet. If needed you can create a new wallet and regain control over your money.